# Win10 OEM key extraction. No MSDM tab

Tags: windows-10, product-key

I just bought a new Dell XPS 13 with win10 pre-installed. I want to completely wipe the drive and install Ubuntu 16.04. But before I do that I would like to extract the oem product key. I've tried using neo-smart tools and rw-everything as well as booting into a linux live cd and extracting it via `cat /sys/firmware...` but nothing works. I don't have an MSDM tab. How can I get my product key?

#

I downloaded and ran showkeyplus and have a field called "installed key". I just want to clarify that if I want to re-install win10, that product key will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Windows 10, but save licence key](http://superuser.com/questions/1063818/uninstall-windows-10-but-save-licence-key)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yes...There is.  The device came with Windows 10 which means its stored within firmware just like Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Comment: [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) will display the key.  Of course getting this key is entirely not required in order to install an OEM Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Ramhhound I had an issue where I installed linux on my older XPS and could no longer install win8.1 or extract the product key. I'm trying to play it safe.

Answer (score 2):

#### I would like to extract the OEM product key

> I just bought a new Dell XPS 13 with win10 pre-installed.

Check the packaging or look at the the Certificate of Authenticity (COA) attached to the PC.

Note:

- As pointed out by Ramhound in a comment you can (re)install an OEM version of Windows 10 without using the product key.

---

#### How to find your Windows 10 product key

> A product key is a 25-character code that's used to activate Windows
>   and looks like this:
>
> PRODUCT KEY: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
>
> Activation helps verify that your copy of Windows hasn't been used on
>   more PCs than the Microsoft Software License Terms allow.
>
> How to find your product key depends on how you bought your copy of
>   Windows 10:
>
> - If you bought Windows 10 from an authorized retailer, the product key will be on a label inside the box it came in.
> - If you bought a digital copy of Windows 10 from a Microsoft website, the product key will be in the confirmation email you
>     received after buying it or will be distributed digitally as an
>     entitlement, in which case you won't receive a product key. For
>     example, if you upgraded to Windows 10 for free, you'll receive an
>     entitlement instead of a product key.
> - If you bought a new PC running Windows 10, the product key will be pre–installed on your PC and your PC will automatically be
>     activated, included with the packaging the PC came in, or included on
>     the Certificate of Authenticity (COA) attached to the PC.

Source [How to find your Windows 10 product key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/product-key-windows-10)

Comment: I had an issue on an older XPS 13 where I couldn't recover or install/activate win8.1. Everyone, including Dell TS said that win8.1 should activate upon installation...which it DID NOT. So I'm just trying to play it safe.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Dell computer.  There should be a Windows 10 sticker on the back.  The Windows key is embedded in the BIOS.  Windows 10 will find it automatically.  MS has done this since Windows 8 with very large OEM's like Dell, HP, Fujitsu, etc.